# How do I build apps to my jailbroken iPad?

Tags: xcode, jailbreak, cydia

I have XCode 3.2.2 and am trying to build an app to my jailbroken iPad. I have followed the tutorial to Fake Code Sign Apps [here](http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=292945) on Multi-Touch forums. On the iPad, I installed [AppSync](http://www.redmondpie.com/appsync-for-ipad-3.2-jailbreak-firmware-9140728/). Still, when I tried to build my app, I got

```
Error Starting Executable

No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected.
```

I think next, I'll try [Cydia's](http://www.saurik.com/id/8) tutorial....which probably woulda made sense to do first anyway. I'll post progress here. But in the meanwhile, any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so clearly, I'm just an idiot. I'm using XCode 3.2.2, which only supports iPad 3.2. My iPad has 3.2.1 installed. Updating my XCode will probably fix this (non) issue lol.

There are three ways to do this:

- Self-Signing (from Xcode)
- Pseudo-Signing (from device)
- Disable Signing

All are detailed and explained [here](http://www.saurik.com/id/8) on Saurik's site.

I went with self-signing. Here's the process for those interested.

### Self-Signing

- **Edit Info.plist** file

  - Located at `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/`.
  - Find three occurrences of "XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext" and replace with "XCCodeSignContext"
- **Create certificate**.

  - Open Keychain Access >> Click Keychain Access >> Certificate Assistant >> Create a Certificate
  - give it any name
  - Self-signed Root
  - Change type to "Code Signing"
  - Check "Override defaults"
  - Click "Continue" until done
- **Build the app** in Xcode.

  - Edit Project Settings >> Set "Code Signing Identity" to the name of the certificate you just created.
  - Select the device you want to build to from the dropdown menu (not simulator)
  - Cmd + B to build
- **Copy to Device**

  - Get the .app file from the build directory (`/build/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app`)
  - SSH the file over to `/Applications` directory on the device
  - Respring/ reboot

Comment: I would like to know if this process works with XCode 4.2 and iOS 4.2 or iOS 5.0

Answer (score 0):

In xcode's menu bar, go to windows->organizer. I don't remember exactly what it looks like, but once you plug in an ios device (aka the iPad) it should appear under devices on the left hand side.  Click on it, and it will take you to a screen with 2 or so buttons on it, one of which will be 'use for development', or something like that.  Clicking this will provision the iPad for development, and everything should work fine after that.  Repeat for all other ipads/phones/touches.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jared. I already have it marked for development. It still won't build to the device though.